# (android)Cant start activity => java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-activity

Im developing an android application. But, i have one problem..
Whenever i run my app through Bluestacks, or Android emulator, i have an such error. It works on my actual phone.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{semo.msoft.yusearch/semo.msoft.yusearch.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

it occured in this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

I have No Idea about this..
please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="semo.msoft.yusearch">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FindActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.YU" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TimeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.YU" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LectureActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.YU" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ScoreActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.YU" />
    <activity android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.YU"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/login_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="semo.msoft.yusearch.LoginActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Member Login"
    android:textColor="#579ce1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_background"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_id"/>


    <EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/id"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:hint="학번을 입력하세요."
    android:textColorHint="#b6b1b1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_background"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pw"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="20"

        android:id="@+id/pw"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="비밀번호를 입력하세요."
        android:textColorHint="#b6b1b1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="로그인"
    android:background="@drawable/rounc_login"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add XML code

Comment: @HareshChhelana I uploaded Layout and Manifest

Comment: would you please remove 
tools:context="semo.msoft.yusearch.LoginActivity"
from xml file and check if it work. @MWP

Comment: @Smartiz Thanks but same error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. If drawable resources are located V21 folder, it can't make an error under some specific version of device. Just put Drawable resource to Drawable Folder.

Answer (score 0):

If the layout exists, it's just because you don't have declared it into your manifest.xml file